# Using QGIS Notebook Extension Compatibility on Windows

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently working on integrating the qgis-nbextension into my workflow on a Windows system. However, I'm encountering compatibility issues and could use some guidance.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Installed QGIS: I've installed QGIS version 3.30.2 on my Windows 10 machine.
- Installed Python: I have Python 3.11.4 installed as well.
- Cloned the Repository: I've cloned the [qgis-nbextension repository](https://github.com/3liz/qgis-nbextension/tree/master) from GitHub.
- Installation: I followed the instructions in the repository's README and used the setup.py file to install the extension using pip.
- Notebook Integration: I'm trying to use the extension in a Jupyter Notebook environment, but when I run the command

  ```
   %qgis --processing
  ```

  I encounter the following error:

  ```
   AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname'
  ```

[image]
[image]

I've checked the repository's documentation and README, but I'm not sure if I'm missing any crucial steps. I'm also uncertain whether this extension is compatible with my version of QGIS, Python, and Windows.

What is wrong?

Comment: That plugin was apparently not written or tested on Windows, [`os.uname`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/os.html#os.uname) is not available on Windows, only Unix like (Linux, MacOS, BSD etc...). There is a [ticket about this](https://github.com/3liz/qgis-nbextension/issues/1), but the developer closed it as they don't use Windows. You could fork (or edit your clone) and make changes to use [`sys.platform`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/sys.html#sys.platform) instead. You'd need to handle Windows specific setup.

Comment: Okay, thank you for explaining!